# Need help to create hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am new to hibernate criteria.please correct me if i am wrong in below code.

```
        Criteria c = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(JdwCustomerTlrdRef.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.ilike("operations_spec", "%AAL%"));

        List<JdwCustomerTlrdRef> customerTlrdRefSysId = c.list();
```

I applied restrictions to operations_spec it will returns all AAL customer name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Criteria c = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(JdwCustomerTlrdRef.class);
```

if you want to find exact "AAL" then

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("operations_spec", "AAL" ));
```

OR if you want all the customer who has AAL in anywhere in `operations_spec` field i.e "abAALcd" then.

```
c.add(Restrictions.like("operations_spec", "AAL" , MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

There is one more thing, you are using field name as "operations_spec", it looks like field name in db. if you want to use in criteria then you should use the property name which I think would be `operationSpecs` if you are following java member name coding practice.

if this is the case then apply restriction like this.

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("operationSpecs", "AAL" ));
```